# Dynamically importing Python modules that require other modules

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, python-import, subclassing

I am working on a script that will load plugins from a directory (`plugins`), and these plugin files should contain a class that is subclassed from a base class (`BaseClass`). I won't know the names of the plugin files or the subclasses, but I plan on finding all the plugin classes with `BaseClass.__subclasses__()`.

In my `main.py` I'm iterating through the `plugins` folder and loading each module like so:

```
pluginlist = []
for pluginfile in pluginfiles :
        pluginlist.append(importlib.import_module(pluginfile))
```

However, when I import them this way, they cannot find the `BaseClass`:

```
    class CustomPlugin(BaseClass) :
NameError: name 'BaseClass' is not defined
```

I've tried defining `BaseClass` in `main.py` and importing it beforehand, and I've tried importing it in the plugin file, but haven't been able to figure out how to get it imported.

What is the best way to import dynamic python modules that rely on other python modules?

**Edit:**

`main.py`:

```
import importlib
import os

plugindir="plugins"
pluginfiles = os.listdir(plugindir)
for pluginfile in pluginfiles :
    testfile = importlib.import_module("plugins."+pluginfile)
print(dir())
```

In the `plugins` folder:

`baseclass.py`:

```
class BaseClass() :
    def __init__(self) :
        print("I am a base class")
```

`customplugin.py`:

```
from .baseclass import BaseClass

class CustomPlugin(BaseClass) :
    def __init__(self) :
        print("I am a custom subclass of BaseClass")
```

Comment: Are you importing the BaseClass correctly from those plugins? They won't share the global module state that the loop is running, every module has a isolated scope that python calls "global"

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly import the BaseClass, since ideally it should reside above the `plugins` directory. When I define BaseClass in a file in `plugins` and import it, I get an error about `plugins.customplugin is not a package`.

Comment: Do those plugins have a `__init__.py` file in their folder? This is what defines a python package

Comment: There is an `__init__.py` in the `plugins` folder, yes.

Comment: Can you share one full minimal plugin? More specifically, how and where are the imports done in it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was including the '.py' in my `importlib.import_module()` statement, changing this:

```
for pluginfile in pluginfiles :
    testfile = importlib.import_module("plugins."+pluginfile)
```

to this:

```
for pluginfile in pluginfiles :
    testfile = importlib.import_module("plugins."+pluginfile.split('.')[0])
```

Solved the import problem. Placing `baseclass.py` in the main folder with `main.py` solved the subclassing problem.